# Spark 3.1 - java dataset filter using FilterFunction<Row>

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, apache-spark-dataset

i want to filter dataset based on some condition in spark 3.1 with java.
this is my input dataset

```
+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|id    |zip   |fulldetails                                                                                                                                                                                             |                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                        |
+------+------+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|123541|123541|{"id":"123","name":"aaaa","nBr":1,"type":{"id":5},"status":{"desc":"NONE"},"mainData":{"proceed":"N","savings":{"processed":{"amount":111}}},"findings":[{"newData":[{"place":{"no":1,"doorNo":2}}]}]}  |         
+------+------+---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

Below is the value of 3rd column which is in Json fromat

```
{
    "id":"123",
    "name":"aaaa",
    "nBr":1,
    "type":{
        "id":5
    },
    "status":{
        "desc":"NONE"
    },
    "mainData":{
        "proceed":"N",
        "savings":{
            "processed":{
                "amount":111.0
            }
        }
    },       
    "findings":[
        {
            "newData":[
                {
                    "place":{
                        "no":1,
                        "doorNo":2
                    }
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
    
}
```

i want to filter this dataset based on the value of 3rd column.
i.e)`mainData.savings.processed.amount < 100.0`  and `name != aaaa`

If we change this Json data to Struct we can filter using normal spark `dataset.filter(col('col_name').geq(lit(0)))`
but iam looking normal filter method in spark3.1-java.
i saw we can do it using FilterFunction. if i use this like below how can i get each data from this Json.

```
dataset.filter((FilterFunction<Row>) row->{
            
        });
```

Can anyone help me on this. Thanks in Advance :)